# Cursor to selected not working while an armature is applied

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, edit-mode

I have a rigged/posed mesh and I want to parent something to one of its vertices. When I go into edit mode on the mesh and select a vertex and use Cursor to Selected, it doesn't move the cursor to selected for seemingly 0 reason.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your problem is that Blender put the 3D cursor on the original vertex position, i.e. its position without the modifier, it doesn't take the armature modifier into account, which can be annoying sometimes when for example you try to modify a mesh that is affected by an armature: The cursor won't come at the vertex or vertices position, it will stick at the original vertex position, not convenient to grab the XYZ widgets. To make it clear:

- Let say you've parented the cube to the bone *With Automatic Weight*.
- Move or rotate the bone in *Pose* mode.
- Select the cube, go in *Edit* mode. Display the cube's *Armature* modifier on your right panel. If you enable the *Adjust Edit Cage to Modifier Result* option, in *Edit* mode you'll see the mesh fitting to its modified position.
- Select a vertex.
- Press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor To Selected*.
- Contrary to what is expected, the 3D cursor doesn't move to the selected vertex. Actually it sticks to the original vertex position, i.e. its position without modifier. It's Blender's choice, it might have some reasons(?).
- If you disable the *Adjust Edit Cage to Modifier Result* option, you can clearly see what I mean, the 3D cursor stays on the original vertex position.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is apply the rig, snap cursor to selection (it allows you to precisely place it not only on a vert but on a selection of verts, too, this way) and then undo the modifier application. The mesh will remain rigged, and the undo operation doesn't change the cursor position so it will stay in the correct spot.